# How to update text in UpdatePanel while app is busy

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a quotation app that has been developed using C#, ASP.net, and AJAX.

The user enters a number of panels and a number of I/O points for each panel, and this app calculated the best combination of controllers for that input. The problem is that this can take a little time and I would like to be able to update the user on the progress while they're waiting.

As soon as the user presses the calculate button, the application begins to work out the combination of controllers in the function below.

The QuoteWizard page handles the steps for the quote and contains a few instances of the 'MiscProducts' control. On the last step, the following function is called.

**QuoteWizard.aspx.cs**

```
protected void CalculateQuote(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var quote = CurrentQuote;

        quote = DataManager.SaveQuote(quote);

        foreach (Panel p in quote.Panels)
        {
            quote = DataManager.RecalculatePanel(quote, p);
        }

        CurrentQuote = quote;

        IntegrationProducts.ProgressBarModalPopupExtender.Hide();

        Response.Redirect(ReviseQuoteUrl, false);
    }
```

So, when the user presses the 'Calculate' button, a progress dialog appears. I have achieved this using a ModalPopupExtender control with an UpdatePanel control as the 'PopupControlID'.

The progress dialog is shown by setting the 'OnClientClick' element for the submit button to show the progress dialog via a javascript function.

In this panel, I give the user an estimated time and I would like to be able to show the user the time that has elapsed so far. I added a timer control with an interval of 1 second and a label to update every tick.

**MiscProducts.acsx**

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
             BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" BehaviorID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender"
             TargetControlID="hiddenField" PopupControlID="ProgressPanel" Enabled="True" 
             DropShadow="true"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProgressPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LoadingLabel" runat="server" Text=" Loading..." />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="ElapsedTimeText" runat="server" Text="Elapsed Time: 0 second(s)" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

And the 'Timer1_Tick' function in code-behind looks like:

```
static int counter = 0;

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        ElapsedTimeText.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0} second(s)", counter);

    }
```

However, this Timer1_Tick function is not hit while the application is busy calculating the quote, and so the label of text is not updated at all.

I also wanted to show the user the progress of each Panel - something like 'Panel 1 of 10'... 'Panel 2 of 10' etc. I tried updating the text label in the 'foreach' loop above, and then calling 'ProgressPanel.Update();' but the text does not change.

Is it possible to update the text of the UpdatePanel while the application is calculating the combos for each panel? Maybe there is something I've missed or am not seeing so hopefully you guys can point it out.

Comment: There are two ways to do the progress bar in ASP 1) Use the SignalR to update the UI or 2) Use the continue AJAX request with separate thread to update the UI.

Comment: @CoderofCode : Thanks. Can you give/link some examples of how I could use the 'continue AJAX request with separate thread to update the UI'? I would rather not add another library (SignalR) to my application, as it is already large enough and space is limited on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the `Progress Bar` using the `ASP` and ajax model pop up then this is the way you can do it.

The Button which fires the processing event

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnLongTask" runat="server" Text="Long Task" OnClick="btnProcessLongTask_Click"/>
```

Then model pop up extender to show the progress bar pop up (I am using Jquery UI progress bar to show the progress bar in place of only changing text)

```
  <div>
        <div>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="popUp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Visible="true"></asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopUpAutoReview" runat="server" TargetControlID="popUp"
        PopupControlID="panelTodisplay" BackgroundCssClass="modal_background" DropShadow="true">
        <Animations>
                <OnShown>
                        <ScriptAction Script="registerModalBackgroundClickEMail();" />  
                </OnShown>
        </Animations>
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelTodisplay" runat="server" CssClass="modal_popup popup_size " Style="display: none;"
        ScrollBars="None">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpInnerUpdatePanel" runat="Server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: right;" class="">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/redX.png" AlternateText="Close"
                        CssClass="modal_close padding_top_right" OnClick="img_btnClose_Click" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal_heading model_heading_background">
                    Auto Review
                </div>

                <asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server" CssClass="modal_popup_content">
                <div class="padding_top_bottom">
                   <b><asp:Label ID="popUpMessage" runat="server" Text="Long task in Progress ..."></asp:Label></b>
                  </div>

                    <div id="progressbar">
                        <div class="progress-label">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="progress-message">
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <div class="modal_heading">
                        <asp:Button CssClass="popUpNo" ID="btnPopUpNo" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"
                            OnClientClick="popupCloseClick();" OnClick="btnPopUpNo_Click" />
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Now the code to show the popup and handle the progress on the click

```
  protected void btnProcessLongTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdlPopUpAutoReview.Show();
        autoReviewThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LongRunningTask));
        autoReviewThread.Start();
        Session["IsStopAutoReview"] = false;
    }
```

Now method which is running your long running task

```
 private LongRunningTask()
  {
   autoReviewProgressValue = 0;
        if (longrunningTasks.count > 0)
        {
           //This for each loop for looping through your task list which can be anything or single task which takes long then you can update the autoReviewProgressValue  after each short process or using the timer.
           foreach(Task task in longRunningTaskList)
           {
            if ((bool)Session["IsStopAutoReview"])
                {
                    ControlVisibility(false);
                    autoReviewThread.Abort();
                }

               int valueToIncreament = int.Parse(Math.Round((double)(100 - autoReviewProgressValue) / (longrunningTasks.Count - longrunningTasks.IndexOf(task)), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString());

                //Your processing of the task 
               If( Processtask(task))
                {
                autoReviewProgressMessage = "Task " + longrunningTasks.IndexOf(task) + " processed sucessfull.";
                }
                else
                    autoReviewProgressMessage = "Task " + longrunningTasks.IndexOf(task)+ " failed to process.";

                autoReviewProgressValue += valueToIncreament;
            }
        }
   }
```

Web method to call from the ajax to get the process updates

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static string ProcessAutoReview()
    {
        return autoReviewProgressValue + "-" + autoReviewProgressMessage;
    }
```

And finally the continues ajax call which will be able to loop through continue and get update.

```
   function updateProgress() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "InvoiceVerification.aspx/ProcessAutoReview",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                var data = msg.d.split('-');
                var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
                    progressLabel = $(".progress-label"),
                    progressTitle = $('#popUpMessage');

                    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: false,
                    change: function () {
                        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
                        progressLabel.css("left", "50%");
                        $('.ui-progressbar-value').css("background", "#05d42b");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        progressLabel.text("Complete!");
                        progressTitle.text("Auto Review Completed.");
                        progressTitle.css("font-weight", "bold");
                        progressLabel.css("left", "42%");
                        $('.ui-progressbar-value').css("background", "#05d42b");
                        $('#btnPopUpNo').prop('value', 'Close');
                    }
                });

                if (oldValue != parseInt(data[0])) {
                    $('.progress-message').append('<p>' + data[1] + '</p>');
                }
                oldValue = parseInt(data[0]);
                progressbar.progressbar("value", oldValue);

                if (oldValue < 100) {
                    setTimeout(updateProgress, 10);
                }
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Call this ajax call in the `document.ready({})` or on click of the `progresstaskButton` click .

if you want to stop the process in between add this event

```
  protected void btnPopUpNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdlPopUpAutoReview.Hide();
        Session["IsStopAutoReview"] = true;
    }
```

Need to make the changes according to your need. But this should do it. If any issue please comment.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm fairly new to C#, and web development so threading in this context is not something I have much experience with. I managed to get the timer working, and the label is is showing the incrementing seconds. One question so far, I start a new thread  for the 'CalculateQuote()'. At the end of this function, I have the 'Response.Redirect(...)' to load the new page with the quote information sumarized for the user which throws a httpException now. "Response is not available in this context'. Where should I call this redirect from?

Comment: Please ask your question as new question with the code snippets. Its not good to discuss new question here as I am unable to see your code and understand any of it.If this solution helped you just accept it as answer and ask a new question. with code snippets and explanation.

Comment: Ok, thanks @CoderOfCode! I managed to get what I asked for working - marking your answer as solution. Although, I did not need the ajax script as all I am updating is labels the information about threading was invaluable!